# Weakly convergence and pointwise convergence of $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

How  to show the below theorem? In fact ,I feel it is not right , if $f(x)\ne 0 $ at zero measure set  , I still have 
$$
\int_\Omega f(x)\varphi(x)dx = 0 ~~~\forall \varphi \in C^\infty_0(\Omega)
$$
What is my mistake ?

> [image]

Comment: $f=0$ is implicitly understood as $f=0$ a.e.

Comment: @JohnMa  THanks. Long time no see you.

Comment: The function you stated is the 0-function in L^2. Remember that there are no actual functions in L^2 but rather their equivalence classes.

Answer (score 0):

Since we work in $L^2$-space, $f=0$ is understood as $f$ belongs to the equivalence class of the function identically equal to $0$ for the equivalence relation "equal almost everywhere".